# Hide Menu Bar in Google Sheets using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanted to hide the menu bar in the Google Sheet I created (I am the owner of the file) to the specified editors using App Script. Would that be possible?

I did the "?rm=minimal" trick in the URL but the app script I created for some parts aren't working.
Thanks for your help!

I am expecting it to hide the menu/tool bars placed in the top view of sheets.